# Widget doesn't run using embed code

Tags: 2013

I want to add this javascript code as a widget:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="cwliga_europa" src="http://desporto.sapo.pt/widgets/competition.js?c=liga_europa"></script>
```

The problem is when i try to add the script to the embed code option, nothing happens. The script doesn't run or doesn't load. I already tried to use other widgets but the same happens.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41121/discussion-on-question-by-miguel-widget-doesnt-run-using-embed-code).

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code in Content Editor Web Part or Script Editor WebPart and place that Web Part on Your page where you want to add this widget.

Comment: Already tried to use that but the same happens. The moment I insert the script, nothing loads.

Comment: simply hit the http://desporto.sapo.pt/widgets/competition.js?c=liga_europa URL on your browser and then check whether your link is working? means it giving you the scripts data?

Comment: That link is working, it leads to a script. I don't think the problem is the script, since I tried another scripts and the same happens.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't tagged the question as SharePoint Online only 2013.

If you are on Office365 it could be scripting is disabled:

[image]
<sub>(source: [qdoscc.com](http://www.qdoscc.com/sites/default/files/spblog72.png))</sub>

Contact your Administrator, he should be able to fix your problem. If he can not... fire him

Comment: I can execute simple scripts like this:

`<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    alert("Hi!");
</script>`

But when I try to execute a script from another page, nothing shows up.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Add a Page

Step 2: In edit mode, click on insert tab from the ribbon then
[image]

Step 3: Copy and paste your widget code.
[image]

[image]
Step 4; Click on insert and save the page.
[image]

Comment: I did the same, step by step but nothing loads, the page stays blank.